# What does / (forward slash) mean in cd?

Tags: linux, bash, centos-6

I use the following  commands to change directory and it generally works fine.

```
[max@localhost max]$ cd /
[max@localhost /]$ cd /home/max/
[max@localhost max]$ pwd
/home/max
```

But today, by mistake, I entered two `//` instead of one `/` and to my surprise, it works as well. So, I tried with various examples and all of them works just fine without giving any sort of an error.

```
[max@localhost /]$ cd /home///////////////max/////////////////////
[max@localhost max]$ pwd
/home/max
[max@localhost max]$ cd /
[max@localhost /]$ cd /////////////////home/max///////////
[max@localhost max]$ pwd
/home/max
```

What does these forward slashes mean (`/` and `///////`) and what do they do and represent?

Answer (score 6):

It's defined by [IEEE standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266):

> A pathname may optionally contain one or more trailing slashes. Multiple successive slashes are considered to be the same as one slash.

There is actually a similar question and the solution is described there: [How Linux handles multiple path separators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file).

Comment: It simplifies combining paths by allowing you to avoid testing for leading or trailing slashes. You can just do `path1 + "/" + path2` and it will work whether or not `path1` has a trailing slash and/or `path2` has a leading slash.